# Hide Active Column when cell value is changed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have been trying to work this out myself for the last few days and caught myself in a bit of a one step forward three steps back cycle. I've been reluctant to bother you thinking this would have been answered somewhere else before now.

The idea is that I have a spreadsheet that has criteria in rows with separate entries in rows; in row 6 it is the status of each column entry, which when changed to "Completed" I would like the column to be hidden.

I've been floundering around with Worksheet_Change and been able to hide specific columns, but not the active column.

Any help offered would be much appreciated and I'm sorry if this has been covered elsewhere, but I've not been able to successfully apply any examples out there.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so we can help fix it

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have to work with worksheet_change events, you have to consider a cycle for it, due to user may delete multiple data at the same time or do a copy paste, if you only consider "Target" It would give a debugger error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ItemMultipleData As Range
For Each ItemMultipleData In Target 'handles multiple cells, paste, del, etc
'your code (instead of using "Target" change to ItemMultipleData. IE:
'If ItemMultipleData.Value = "Completed" Then
Next ItemMultipleData 
End Sub
```

Comment: Your point is correct *(+1)*, in my code, I only process a **single change** by restricting `Target.Count` to be **1** ................I will edit my answer to mention this restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point.  It only checks row # **6**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("6:6")

    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "Completed" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This approach assumes that only **one** cell at a time is being changed........that makes it easy to "find the active cell"

Comment: Gary's Student should be the Gary's Master! Thank you so much, I've included each of the lines in various guises but not in this order, I'm a struggling amateur at best, and I honestly appreciate your help.

Comment: If I may, there's some error for example if you parse lots of data (or erase), it will give error because of target being pointed to one cell. Whenever I use Worksheet_change Event, I do a cycle for it, I'll post for this.